# Acumatica: How to use report designer to display both line and line details in one report?

Tags: report, acumatica

Acumatica has some master-child or line--line details relationship tables. For example, SOShipline and SOshiplinesplit.
Is it possible that use report designer to design a report or a report with sub reports to display both Shipline and the linedetails at one time.
Looks like below

[An invoice sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaWFP.png)

I would like to display both shipment lines and its line details under each main line on a printed form, such as invoice.
Could this be done by report designer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that layout with groups, no need to involve the use of sub-reports.

I've created an example below that place the SOShipLine in a group and the SOShipLineSplits in the group detail section.

This is the layout in Report Designer:
[image]

The rendered report:
[image]

Here is this example report source code. You can save it as a UTF-8 encoded text file with extension '.rpx' and open that file with Acumatica Report Designer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report Name="report1">
  <ExcelColumns>
    <item>10</item>
    <item>13</item>
    <item>10</item>
    <item>11</item>
    <item>15</item>
    <item>15</item>
    <item>35</item>
    <item>18</item>
    <item>12</item>
    <item>10</item>
    <item>12</item>
    <item>12</item>
  </ExcelColumns>
  <ExcelMode>Manual</ExcelMode>
  <Filters>
    <FilterExp>
      <DataField>SOShipLine.ShipmentNbr</DataField>
      <OpenBraces>1</OpenBraces>
      <Operator>Or</Operator>
      <Value>@ShipmentNbr</Value>
    </FilterExp>
  </Filters>
  <GridSize>4px, 4px</GridSize>
  <PageSettings>
    <Landscape>True</Landscape>
  </PageSettings>
  <Parameters>
    <ReportParameter>
      <ColumnSpan>2</ColumnSpan>
      <Name>ShipmentNbr</Name>
      <Nullable>True</Nullable>
      <Prompt>Shipment Nbr.</Prompt>
      <Required>True</Required>
      <ViewName>=Report.GetFieldSchema('SOShipment.ShipmentNbr')</ViewName>
    </ReportParameter>
  </Parameters>
  <Relations>
    <ReportRelation>
      <ChildName>SOShipLine</ChildName>
      <Links>
        <RelationRow>
          <ChildField>SOShipLine.ShipmentNbr</ChildField>
          <ParentField>SOShipment.ShipmentNbr</ParentField>
        </RelationRow>
      </Links>
      <ParentName>SOShipment</ParentName>
    </ReportRelation>
    <ReportRelation>
      <ChildName>SOShipLineSplit</ChildName>
      <Links>
        <RelationRow>
          <ChildField>SOShipment.ShipmentNbr</ChildField>
          <ParentField>SOShipLineSplit.ShipmentNbr</ParentField>
        </RelationRow>
        <RelationRow>
          <ChildField>SOShipLine.LineNbr</ChildField>
          <ParentField>SOShipLineSplit.LineNbr</ParentField>
        </RelationRow>
      </Links>
      <ParentName>SOShipLine</ParentName>
    </ReportRelation>
  </Relations>
  <SchemaUrl>http://localhost/2018R2/</SchemaUrl>
  <StylesTemplate>TemplateReport.rpx</StylesTemplate>
  <Tables>
    <ReportTable Name="SOShipment">
      <Fields>
        <ReportField Name="Selected">
          <DataType>Boolean</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="ShipmentNbr"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="ShipDate">
          <DataType>DateTime</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="Operation"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="ShipmentType"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="CustomerID"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="CustomerLocationID"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="Billable">
          <DataType>Boolean</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="SiteID"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="DestinationSiteID"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="ShipAddressID">
          <DataType>Int32</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="ShipContactID">
          <DataType>Int32</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="FOBPoint"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="ShipVia"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="Resedential">
          <DataType>Boolean</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="SaturdayDelivery">
          <DataType>Boolean</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="LabelsPrinted">
          <DataType>Boolean</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="ShippedViaCarrier">
          <DataType>Boolean</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="ShipTermsID"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="ShipZoneID"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="LineTotal">
          <DataType>Decimal</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="CuryID"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="CuryInfoID">
          <DataType>Int64</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="CuryFreightCost">
          <DataType>Decimal</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="FreightCost">
          <DataType>Decimal</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="CuryFreightAmt">
          <DataType>Decimal</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="FreightAmt">
          <DataType>Decimal</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="CuryPremiumFreightAmt">
          <DataType>Decimal</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="PremiumFreightAmt">
          <DataType>Decimal</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="CuryTotalFreightAmt">
          <DataType>Decimal</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="TotalFreightAmt">
          <DataType>Decimal</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="TaxCategoryID"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="NoteID">
          <DataType>Int64</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="NoteText"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="NoteFiles"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="NoteImages"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="Hold">
          <DataType>Boolean</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="Confirmed">
          <DataType>Boolean</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="Released">
          <DataType>Boolean</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="Status"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="LineCntr">
          <DataType>Int16</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="ControlQty">
          <DataType>Decimal</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="ShipmentQty">
          <DataType>Decimal</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="ShipmentWeight">
          <DataType>Decimal</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="OrderWeight">
          <DataType>Decimal</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="ShipmentVolume">
          <DataType>Decimal</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="OrderVolume">
          <DataType>Decimal</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="PackageLineCntr">
          <DataType>Int16</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="PackageWeight">
          <DataType>Decimal</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="CreatedByID"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="CreatedByScreenID"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="CreatedDateTime">
          <DataType>DateTime</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="LastModifiedByID"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="LastModifiedByScreenID"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="LastModifiedDateTime">
          <DataType>DateTime</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="tstamp">
          <DataType>Object</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="Hidden">
          <DataType>Boolean</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="WorkgroupID"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="OwnerID"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="FreeItemQtyTot">
          <DataType>Decimal</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="StatusIsNull"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="CustomerID_BAccountR_acctName"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="CustomerID_description"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="CustomerLocationID_Location_descr"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="CustomerLocationID_description"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="SiteID_INSite_descr"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="SiteID_description"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="DestinationSiteID_INSite_descr"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="DestinationSiteID_description"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="ShipVia_Carrier_description"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="ShipVia_description"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="CuryViewState">
          <DataType>Boolean</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="TaxCategoryID_TaxCategory_descr"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="TaxCategoryID_description"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="NoteActivity"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="CreatedByID_Creator_username"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="CreatedByID_description"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="LastModifiedByID_Modifier_username"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="LastModifiedByID_description"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="WorkgroupID_EPCompanyTree_description"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="WorkgroupID_description"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="OwnerID_EPEmployee_acctName"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="OwnerID_description"></ReportField>
      </Fields>
      <FullName>PX.Objects.SO.SOShipment</FullName>
    </ReportTable>
    <ReportTable Name="SOShipLine">
      <Fields>
        <ReportField Name="ShipmentNbr"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="ShipmentType"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="LineNbr">
          <DataType>Int16</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="CustomerID">
          <DataType>Int32</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="ShipDate">
          <DataType>DateTime</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="Confirmed">
          <DataType>Boolean</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="Released">
          <DataType>Boolean</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="LineType"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="Operation"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="OrigOrderType"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="OrigOrderNbr"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="OrigLineNbr">
          <DataType>Int16</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="InventoryID"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="TranType"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="PlanType"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="SubItemID"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="SiteID"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="LocationID"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="LotSerialNbr"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="InvtMult">
          <DataType>Int16</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="ExpireDate">
          <DataType>DateTime</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="UOM"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="ShippedQty">
          <DataType>Decimal</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="Qty">
          <DataType>Decimal</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="BaseShippedQty">
          <DataType>Decimal</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="BaseQty">
          <DataType>Decimal</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="UnassignedQty">
          <DataType>Decimal</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="UnitCost">
          <DataType>Decimal</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="ExtCost">
          <DataType>Decimal</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="OrderUOM"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="UnitPrice">
          <DataType>Decimal</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="DiscPct">
          <DataType>Decimal</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="LineAmt">
          <DataType>Decimal</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="AlternateID"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="TranDesc"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="UnitWeigth">
          <DataType>Decimal</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="UnitVolume">
          <DataType>Decimal</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="ExtWeight">
          <DataType>Decimal</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="ExtVolume">
          <DataType>Decimal</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="ProjectID">
          <DataType>Int32</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="TaskID">
          <DataType>Int32</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="ReasonCode"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="IsFree">
          <DataType>Boolean</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="ManualDisc">
          <DataType>Boolean</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="DetDiscIDC1"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="DetDiscSeqIDC1"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="DetDiscIDC2"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="DetDiscSeqIDC2"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="DetDiscApp">
          <DataType>Boolean</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="DocDiscIDC1"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="DocDiscSeqIDC1"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="DocDiscIDC2"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="DocDiscSeqIDC2"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="NoteID">
          <DataType>Int64</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="NoteText"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="NoteFiles"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="NoteImages"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="CreatedByID"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="CreatedByScreenID"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="CreatedDateTime">
          <DataType>DateTime</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="LastModifiedByID"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="LastModifiedByScreenID"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="LastModifiedDateTime">
          <DataType>DateTime</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="tstamp">
          <DataType>Object</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="CuryExtPrice">
          <DataType>Decimal</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="CuryLineAmt">
          <DataType>Decimal</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="CuryDiscAmt">
          <DataType>Decimal</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="CuryUnitPrice">
          <DataType>Decimal</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="CuryInfoID">
          <DataType>Int64</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="HasKitComponents">
          <DataType>Boolean</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="HasSerialComponents">
          <DataType>Boolean</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="InventoryID_InventoryItem_descr"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="InventoryID_description"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="SiteID_INSite_descr"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="SiteID_description"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="LocationID_INLocation_descr"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="LocationID_description"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="ReasonCode_ReasonCode_descr"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="ReasonCode_description"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="NoteActivity"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="CreatedByID_Creator_username"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="CreatedByID_description"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="LastModifiedByID_Modifier_username"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="LastModifiedByID_description"></ReportField>
      </Fields>
      <FullName>PX.Objects.SO.SOShipLine</FullName>
    </ReportTable>
    <ReportTable Name="SOShipLineSplit">
      <Fields>
        <ReportField Name="AssignedNbr"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="BaseQty">
          <DataType>Decimal</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="Confirmed">
          <DataType>Boolean</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="CreatedByID"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="CreatedByID_Creator_displayName"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="CreatedByID_Creator_Username"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="CreatedByID_description"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="CreatedByScreenID"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="CreatedDateTime">
          <DataType>DateTime</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="CreatedDateTime_Day"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="CreatedDateTime_Hour"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="CreatedDateTime_Month"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="CreatedDateTime_Quarter"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="ExpireDate">
          <DataType>DateTime</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="ExpireDate_Day"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="ExpireDate_Hour"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="ExpireDate_Month"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="ExpireDate_Quarter"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="InventoryID"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="InventoryID_description"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="InventoryID_InventoryItem_descr"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="InventoryID_Segment1"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="InvtMult">
          <DataType>Int16</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="IsComponentItem">
          <DataType>Boolean</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="IsStockItem">
          <DataType>Boolean</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="IsUnassigned">
          <DataType>Boolean</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="LastLotSerialNbr"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="LastModifiedByID"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="LastModifiedByID_description"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="LastModifiedByID_Modifier_displayName"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="LastModifiedByID_Modifier_Username"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="LastModifiedByScreenID"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="LastModifiedDateTime">
          <DataType>DateTime</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="LastModifiedDateTime_Day"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="LastModifiedDateTime_Hour"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="LastModifiedDateTime_Month"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="LastModifiedDateTime_Quarter"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="LineNbr">
          <DataType>Int32</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="LineType"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="LocationID"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="LocationID_description"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="LocationID_INLocation_descr"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="LocationID_Segment1"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="LotSerClassID"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="LotSerialNbr"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="Operation"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="OrigLineNbr">
          <DataType>Int32</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="OrigOrderNbr"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="OrigOrderType"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="OrigPlanType"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="OrigSplitLineNbr">
          <DataType>Int32</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="PlanID">
          <DataType>Int64</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="PlanType"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="ProjectID">
          <DataType>Int32</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="Qty">
          <DataType>Decimal</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="Released">
          <DataType>Boolean</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="ShipDate">
          <DataType>DateTime</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="ShipDate_Day"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="ShipDate_Hour"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="ShipDate_Month"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="ShipDate_Quarter"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="ShipmentNbr"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="SiteID"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="SiteID_description"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="SiteID_INSite_descr"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="SiteID_Segment1"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="SplitLineNbr">
          <DataType>Int32</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="SubItemID"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="SubItemID_Segment1"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="TaskID">
          <DataType>Int32</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="TranDate">
          <DataType>DateTime</DataType>
        </ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="TranType"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="tstamp"></ReportField>
        <ReportField Name="UOM"></ReportField>
      </Fields>
      <FullName>PX.Objects.SO.SOShipLineSplit</FullName>
    </ReportTable>
  </Tables>
  <Sections>
    <PageHeader Name="pageHeaderSection1">
      <ExcelMargin>
        <bottom>1</bottom>
      </ExcelMargin>
      <GridSize>8px, 8px</GridSize>
      <Height>0.21164cm</Height>
    </PageHeader>
    <Detail Name="groupDetails">
      <GridSize>8px, 8px</GridSize>
      <Height>14px</Height>
      <Items>
        <TextBox Name="textBox40">
          <Excel>
            <column>7</column>
          </Excel>
          <Location>136px, 0px</Location>
          <Size>744px, 14px</Size>
          <StyleName>Normal</StyleName>
          <Value>=[SOShipLineSplit.LotSerialNbr]</Value>
        </TextBox>
      </Items>
    </Detail>
    <PageHeader Name="pageHeaderSection2">
      <GridSize>8px, 8px</GridSize>
      <Height>0.21164cm</Height>
      <StyleName>ColumnsHeaderSection</StyleName>
    </PageHeader>
  </Sections>
  <Items />
  <Groups>
    <Group Name="group1">
      <Grouping>
        <GroupExp>
          <DataField>SOShipLine.LineNbr</DataField>
        </GroupExp>
      </Grouping>
      <Headers>
        <Header Name="groupHeaderSection1">
          <GridSize>8px, 8px</GridSize>
          <Height>0.84656cm</Height>
          <PrintOnEveryPage>True</PrintOnEveryPage>
          <StyleName>GroupHighlight</StyleName>
          <Items>
            <TextBox Name="textBox32">
              <Excel>
                <column>3</column>
              </Excel>
              <Location>0px, 16px</Location>
              <NavigateMethod>Server</NavigateMethod>
              <Size>880px, 14px</Size>
              <StyleName>Heading 1</StyleName>
              <Value>=[SOShipLine.InventoryID]</Value>
            </TextBox>
            <TextBox Name="textBox60">
              <Location>0px, 0px</Location>
              <Size>880px, 14px</Size>
              <StyleName>Heading 1</StyleName>
              <Value>Ship Line Item</Value>
            </TextBox>
          </Items>
        </Header>
        <Header Name="groupHeaderSection2">
          <GridSize>8px, 8px</GridSize>
          <Height>20px</Height>
          <StyleName>GroupL1Highlight</StyleName>
          <Items>
            <TextBox Name="textBox27">
              <Location>136px, 0px</Location>
              <Size>744px, 14px</Size>
              <StyleName>Heading 1</StyleName>
              <Value>='Ship Line Split Lot SerialNbr for item ' + [SOShipLine.InventoryID]</Value>
            </TextBox>
          </Items>
        </Header>
      </Headers>
      <Footers>
        <Footer Name="groupFooterSection1">
          <GridSize>8px, 8px</GridSize>
          <Height>0.21164cm</Height>
        </Footer>
        <Footer Name="groupFooterSection2">
          <ExcelMargin>
            <bottom>1</bottom>
          </ExcelMargin>
          <GridSize>8px, 8px</GridSize>
          <Height>7px</Height>
        </Footer>
      </Footers>
    </Group>
  </Groups>
</Report>
```

Comment: Fantastic, it works.Thank you so much.
Just one more question, take your SN show for example, is it possbile to print the SN in landscape way? I mean, rows to columns.
If I just want to show the SN, and there are a lot of for 1 shipline. It would be better if I can show 10 SNs in one line instead of 10 sub lines under 1 shipline.

Comment: Hello Pal, It looks like I can use tabular report to fulfill my need. However, I've met another problem. Could you please give me another hand? 
I've posted another question at
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53239823/acumaticatabular-report-generates-unexpected-lines-when-calling-as-sub-report
Thank you very much in advance.