# Acumatica:Tabular Report generates unexpected lines when calling as sub report

Tags: report, acumatica, tabular

Using Acumatica report designer, I've designed a tabular report to fetch one field from SOShiplinesplit.The report's main parameters are RefNbr and ShipLineNbr. If run the tabular report individually, for 1 doc's 1 shipline，its result looks like below:
[Tabular Report results when running individually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/saRLc.png)

However, if I add this tabular as a subreport like below,
[Add Tabular report as a subreport at ShiplineNbr group level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylc2d.png)

I met with confusing results if I run the master report to call tabular report
[Run within master report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9N37X.png)

Could anyone give me a hand to get out of this trouble?

Comment: This answer mentions using the TabularFreeze property to solve that issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551488/tabular-sub-report-property

Comment: Hello, I looked and studied this post carefully before I posted my own question.
It looks like something is wrong with the calling mechnism.
In tabular report, if I set the layout [SOShipLineSplit.SplitLineNbr] "The red line"  [SOShipLineSplit.Qty] in top group header, when passed parameter shiplineNbr=9 to it, it just executed 1 time with only the first SplitLineNbr displayed. If run within the master report, all the shipsplitLineNbr under shiplineNbr be displayed.
Did I explain clearly? If not, could you reach me at michael.wang@orderock.com, or give me one possible way to send you my rpx

Comment: You can open the rpx with a text editor and copy the content in your questions.

Comment: Unfortunatly, even if I have cut the rpx to minmum, it still over the charaters limitations. So would you mind fetching my rpx at https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ROqO_Std4WwGVz5PP4IkiQFBl_xa6XyP